# How does the TSA dog expedite the screening process?

Tags: tsa

As I understand it, the purpose of the TSA dog is to [detect explosives](https://www.tsa.gov/news/passenger-screening-canine-teams-work-to-detect-explosives).  It was communicated to me that dog is constrained resource that would somehow alleviate a bottleneck.  How would having an unlimited supply of TSA dogs alleviate long wait-times?

Comment: The TSA staff need somebody to handle the paperwork.

Comment: @Malvolio in the same way that my dog handled my homework when I was in school.

Comment: Who claims the dog is there to "expedite the screening process?"

Comment: They don't actually say it's to expedite the screening process.  Detection canines are widely used around the world by real security agencies such as CBP/Border Patrol.  Unsurprisingly, it took TSA 12 years to realize this.  I think the initial batch were borrowed or trained by CBP.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a handler will walk with the dog along a line of luggage or passengers. The dog will 'alert' if it smells something it's be trained to notice like chemicals used in explosives or food. An alert can be a bark or the dog sits down, something like that.

I've seen dogs working at baggage claim and at lines for security screening.

Comment: As well as currency